# CALayer - animating layer size blocks animation from running

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-animation, calayer, catransaction

I have a method in which a bunch of layers are positioned, and a single "activated" layer (basically a layer that the user has clicked on) is both positioned and resized at the same time. All the layers, including the activated layer are sublayers of a larger layer. Here is my method:

```
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7]
                     forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
    }];
    for (CALayer *layer in self.inactiveLayers) {
       ... do some positioning ...
    }
    CGRect newFrame = activeLayer.frame;
    newFrame.origin.x = 50.0;
    newFrame.origin.y = 50.0;
    newFrame.size.width = 100.0;
    newFrame.size.height = 100.0;
    activeLayer.frame = newFrame;
    [CATransaction commit];
```

The problem I'm experiencing is really weird. Using the code above, none of the animations run (not even the animations for the inactive layers). But as soon as I comment out the lines that set the size and width of the new frame, the animations magically start working again.

Is there any reason this should be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem, I had a layout manager set on the superlayer of the layers I was trying to animate, and the layout code (which reset the sizes of the layers) was being called when the layer bounds changed. Disabling the layout manager for the duration of the animation solved the issue.

Comment: There you have it! I was thinking about that doc and I know that you can animate changes in the frame of CAScrollLayer. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the frame property of a CAlayer is not animatable. Use the bounds property instead and the position animation will run without a hitch.

Comment: If you are wondering why the position animation works on its own even though you are changing the frame origin (which is not an animatble property) it is because the frame is computed from the bounds and position properties which *are* both animatable. The frame is computed, not stored. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/frame

Comment: I thought that frame was not an explicitly animatable property, but still worked for implicit animation. This has been my experience in the past (setting the frame property automatically animates a layer to its new frame). Just to confirm, I tried just setting the bounds of the layer to my desired size, and it still does not work.